# C# Issue with converting from json

Tags: c#, json, wordpress, datacontractjsonserializer

I want to get posts from a test site with WordPress. When I am debugging, I can see that I get the data from web, but when I try to put them in a TextBox, they don't seem to exist. I used a website to create the classes from C#, but I think that the issue is in my code. I call the method like this:

```
RootObject myPosts = await Class1.Get();
```

Then, to show the values in to the user, I do:

```
textBox1.Text = myPosts.id + " - " + myPosts.author+ "-" + myPosts.title;
```

Code:

```
public class Class1
{
    public async static Task<RootObject> Get()
    {
         var http = new HttpClient();
        var response = await http.GetAsync("http://bearlike-attackers.000webhostapp.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?search=TEST");
        var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(RootObject));

        var ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(result));
        var data = (RootObject)serializer.ReadObject(ms);
        return data;
    }
}
    [DataContract]
    public class Guid
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string rendered { get; set; }
    }
    [DataContract]
    public class Title
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string title { get; set; }
    }
    [DataContract]
    public class Content
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string rendered { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public bool @protected { get; set; }
    }
    [DataContract]
    public class Excerpt
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string rendered { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public bool @protected { get; set; }
    }
    [DataContract]
    public class Self
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string href { get; set; }
    }
    [DataContract]
    public class Collection
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string href { get; set; }
    }
    [DataContract]
    public class About
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string href { get; set; }
    }
    [DataContract]
    public class Author
    {
        [DataMember]
        public bool embeddable { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string href { get; set; }
    }
    [DataContract]
    public class Reply
    {
        [DataMember]
        public bool embeddable { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string href { get; set; }
    }
    [DataContract]
    public class VersionHistory
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string href { get; set; }
    }
    [DataContract]
    public class WpAttachment
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string href { get; set; }
    }
    [DataContract]
    public class WpTerm
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string taxonomy { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public bool embeddable { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string href { get; set; }
    }
    [DataContract]
    public class Cury
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string name { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string href { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public bool templated { get; set; }
    }
    /*
    public class Links
    {
        public List<Self> self { get; set; }
        public List<Collection> collection { get; set; }
        public List<About> about { get; set; }
        public List<Author> author { get; set; }
        public List<Reply> replies { get; set; }
        public List<VersionHistory> __invalid_name__version-history { get; set; }
    public List<WpAttachment> __invalid_name__wp:attachment { get; set; }
public List<WpTerm> __invalid_name__wp:term { get; set; }
    public List<Cury> curies { get; set; }
}
*/
    [DataContract]
    public class RootObject
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string date { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public int id { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string date_gmt { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public Guid guid { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string modified { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string modified_gmt { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string slug { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string type { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string link { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public Title title { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public Content content { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public Excerpt excerpt { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public int author { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public int featured_media { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string comment_status { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string ping_status { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public bool sticky { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string template { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string format { get; set; }
        /*
            [DataMember]
            public List<object> meta { get; set; }

            [DataMember]
            public List<int> categories { get; set; }

            [DataMember]
            public List<object> tags { get; set; }


            [DataMember]
           public Links _links { get; set; }
           */
    }

}
```

Comment: _"when i try to put them in TextBox, they dont seem to exist"_ - can you show the code where you try to display them?

Comment: textBox1.Text = myPosts.id + " - " + myPosts.author+ "-" + myPosts.title;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you paste your URL to http://jsonlint.com/, you will see that the formatted JSON looks like this:

```
[{
    "id": 4,
    "date": "2017-02-16T14:28:41",
    "date_gmt": "2017-02-16T13:28:41",
    "guid": {
        "rendered": "https:\/\/bearlike-attackers.000webhostapp.com\/?p=4"
    },
    "modified": "2017-02-16T14:28:41",
    "modified_gmt": "2017-02-16T13:28:41",
    "slug": "testy",
    "type": "post",
    "link": "https:\/\/bearlike-attackers.000webhostapp.com\/2017\/02\/16\/testy\/",
    "title": {
        "rendered": "Testy"
    },
// And many other properties.

}]
```

Notice the outer `[` and `]`?  Your problem is that your outer JSON container is an array, not an object.   As explained in the [JSON standard](http://www.json.org/):

- An array is an ordered collection of values. An array begins with `[` (left bracket) and ends with `]` (right bracket). Values are separated by `,` (comma).
- An object is an unordered set of name/value pairs. An object begins with `{` (left brace) and ends with `}` (right brace).

`DataContractJsonSerializer` serializes JSON arrays from and to .Net collection types such as `List<T>` and `T []`.  Thus you must deserialize as follows:

```
public async static Task<List<RootObject>> Get()
{
    var http = new HttpClient();
    var response = await http.GetAsync("http://bearlike-attackers.000webhostapp.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?search=TEST");
    var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(List<RootObject>));
    var ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(result));
    var list = (List<RootObject>)serializer.ReadObject(ms);
    return list;
}
```

If you are sure your service will only return one item, you can return a single `RootObject` by using [`Enumerable.SingleOrDefault()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342451.aspx):

```
    return list.SingleOrDefault();
```

It is a little surprising to me that `DataContractJsonSerializer` silently does nothing in such a case.  [json.net](/questions/tagged/json.net) throws an [`Unexpected token: StartArray`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17972326) exception in such cases.

Finally, the property name used for the title is `"rendered"` not `"title"`.  Thus your `Title` class needs to look like:

```
[DataContract]
public class Title
{
    [DataMember]
    public string rendered { get; set; }
}
```

And to access its value, do (adding any null checks as required):

```
var s = myPost.id + " - " + myPost.author + "-" + myPost.title.rendered;
```

(I haven't checked correctness of your other data contract member names.  You should, since one was incorrect.)

Comment: I completely overlooked [], thank you for pointing that out. I guess that I have to change RootObject myPosts = await Class1.Get();  to List<RootObject> myPosts = await Class1.Get(); .